# Inversion on symmetrical relation becomes circular in Coq

Tags: coq, symmetric, inversion

One possible way to say that `n m : nat` are adjacent even numbers in Coq is to define that relation inductively, beginning with 0 and 2.

```
Inductive adj_ev : nat -> nat -> Prop :=
| ae_0 : adj_ev 0 2
| ae_1 : forall ( n m : nat ), adj_ev n m -> adj_ev m ( S ( S m ) )
| ae_2 : forall ( n m : nat ), adj_ev n m -> adj_ev m n.
```

`ae_0` states that 0 and 2 are adjacent even numbers. `ae_1` states that if some `n m : nat` are adjacent even numbers, so are `m` and `m + 2`. With these two constructors we can cover all pairs of adjacent even numbers up to infinity. But wait! This works for `n` and `m` if and only if `n < m`. So we need the last constructor `ae_2` that flips any given number pair in the relation.

Now that I've defined the relation, I want to do some sanity checks on it to make sure it works. For instance, I know that 1 and 3 are not adjacent even numbers, and I also know that `adj_ev 1 3` can never be obtained from the way I defined `adj_ev`. So I can surely *prove* that `~ ( adj_ev 1 3 )`, right?

```
Theorem test' : ~ ( adj_ev 1 3 ).
unfold not. intros H.
inversion H. inversion H0.
```

After a few inversions I quickly get stuck in an infinite loop. It's like I'm asking Coq, "How can `n` and `m` be adjacent and even?" Coq answers "well, perhaps `m` and `n` are adjacent and even..." Then I ask, "How are `m` and `n` adjacent and even?" Coq says "well, perhaps `n` and `m` are adjacent and even..." ad infinitum.

The general problem is that, when you have some inductively defined symmetrical relation `R`, it is easy to show that `R` holds where it really does hold, but difficult to show that it doesn't where it doesn't. Perhaps there is a better tactic than `inversion` for extracting a contradiction in such cases, but I'm not sure what it might be.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I tried `induction` with some extra equations, but that wasn't enough.

```
Goal forall n1 n2, adj_ev n1 n2 -> n1 = 1 -> n2 = 3 -> False.
Proof. induction 1. Abort.
```

I managed to prove your theorem by first proving that two adjacent even numbers are even.

Enable rewriting with equivalence relations.

```
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
```

Turn off proof search when using `firstorder`. Allow only simplification.

```
Set Firstorder Depth 0.
```

Create a hint database `Hints` for use with `auto`, `autorewrite`, or `autounfold`.

```
Create HintDb Hints.
```

Shorthand for commonly used tactics.

```
Ltac simplify := repeat (firstorder || subst || autorewrite with Hints in *).

Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
  | even_0 : even 0
  | even_S : forall n1, even n1 -> even (S (S n1)).
```

Simple enough.

```
Conjecture C1 : even 0 <-> True.
Conjecture C2 : even 1 <-> False.
Conjecture C3 : forall n1, even (S (S n1)) <-> even n1.

Hint Rewrite C1 C2 C3 : Hints.

Theorem T1 : forall n1 n2, adj_ev n1 n2 -> even n1 /\ even n2.
Proof. induction 1; simplify. Qed.

Goal ~ adj_ev 1 3. Proof. intro H1. apply T1 in H1. simplify. Qed.
```

You could have also defined

```
Definition least : (nat -> Prop) -> nat -> Prop := fun p1 n1 => p1 n1 /\ (forall n2, p1 n2 -> n2 >= n1).

Definition greatest : (nat -> Prop) -> nat -> Prop := fun p1 n1 => p1 n1 /\ (forall n2, p1 n2 -> n2 <= n1).

Definition even : nat -> Prop := fun n1 => exists n2, n1 = 2 * n2.

Definition least_greater_even : nat -> nat -> Prop := fun n1 => least (fun n2 => n2 > n1 /\ even n2).

Definition greatest_less_even : nat -> nat -> Prop := fun n1 => greatest (fun n2 => n2 < n1 /\ even n2).

Definition adjacent_even : nat -> nat -> Prop := fun n1 n2 => least_greater_even n1 n2 /\ greatest_less_even n2 n1 \/ greatest_less_even n1 n2 /\ least_greater_even n2 n1.
```

and worked from there. And there are other ways of defining your predicate.

```
Inductive adj_ev : nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | adj_ev_0_2 : adj_ev 0 2
  | adj_ev_2_0 : adj_ev 2 0
  | adj_ev_S_S : forall n1 n2, adj_ev n1 n2 -> adj_ev (S (S n1)) (S (S n2)).

Goal ~ adj_ev 1 3. Proof. inversion 1. Qed.
```